# underscore.js error while generating td elements

Tags: underscore.js

Underscore does seem to have a problem with generating html `td` tags.

The following code works:

```
<% _.each(table_heads, function(head, index) { %>
<li><%= head %></li>
<% }); %>
```

This does not work (cause: `<td>` tag production):

```
<% _.each(table_heads, function(head, index) { %>
 <td><%= head %></td>
<% }); %>
```

Console message: `head is not defined`.

I also changed the template settings for interpolate to the following:

```
interpolate:/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
```

But the error message from above stays the same.

Comment: Can't reproduce, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jacob414/9BaHS/1/)

Answer (score 1):

head is not defined clearly shows 1 of your elements in the json array is missing the 'head' attribute.

could you perhaps add the json that you are passing to the template.